# How to modify a woocommerce includes file without editing the core file? or is there a way to duplicate includes file to childtheme?

Tags: php, woocommerce, include

On woocommerce includes folder I edited a php file there which is the class-wc-customer-download-log-data-store.php in this code below:

```
/**
 * Create download log entry.
 *
 * @param WC_Customer_Download_Log $download_log Customer download log object.
 */
public function create( WC_Customer_Download_Log &$download_log ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Always set a timestamp.
    if ( is_null( $download_log->get_timestamp( 'edit' ) ) ) {
        $download_log->set_timestamp( time() );
    }

    $data = array(
        'timestamp'       => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $download_log->get_timestamp( 'edit' )->getTimestamp() ),
        'permission_id'   => $download_log->get_permission_id( 'edit' ),
        'user_id'         => $download_log->get_user_id( 'edit' ),
        'user_ip_address' => $download_log->get_user_ip_address( 'edit' ),
    );

    $format = array(
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
    );

    $result = $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . self::get_table_name(),
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_downloadable_product_download_log_insert_data', $data ),
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_downloadable_product_download_log_insert_format', $format, $data )
    );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_downloadable_product_download_log_insert', $data );

    if ( $result ) {
        $download_log->set_id( $wpdb->insert_id );
        $download_log->apply_changes();
    } else {
    //  wp_die( esc_html__( 'Unable to insert download log entry in database.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
```

If you notice that on line 67 I commented out this line

```
    wp_die( esc_html__( 'Unable to insert download log entry in database.', 'woocommerce' ) );
```

Now how to achieve this without editing the code file? I wanted to copy and paste this file to childtheme but it didnt work. Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: The filename beginning with `class-` means, it is not actually a template file to begin with.  There is no mechanism for “overriding” class files. Hooks/filters are the only way, you are supposed to use to modify anything about the application logic at this point. Why do you want to “comment this out” in the first place?

Comment: Hi @CBroe this is because users are unable to download the file. Any tips on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: sorry @CBroe I know a little in php. If you get a chance or if its just a few lines to make it work, much appreciated if you can guide me or can you code it for me? thank you so much